# Euler's theorem using Lagrange's theorem?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

How to prove Euler's theorem using Lagrange's theorem?

> If $a$ and $n$ are relatively prime then $a^{\phi(n)}\equiv 1 \pmod n$

Wikipedia says that it can done and that $\phi(n)$ is the order of the multiplicative group of integers modulo $n$. But I'm not sure how to proceed with the proof. Any ideas/hints?

Comment: This is a duplicate, so as much as I would want to provide my input, it has already been done justice. Lagrange's theorem is simply overkill by the way.

Comment: @JefferyOpoku-Mensah I am aware of the non-group theory proof, but wanted to know the one which uses group theory

Comment: Ah. I should say the proof is still group-theoretic. It is pretty much the restriction of Lagrange's theorem to abelian groups in fact, so the details carry over, except the argument is clouded with the one line phrase "Lagrange's theorem."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\gcd(a,n)=1$ we have that $\overline{a}\in(\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z})^*$. The order of $\overline{a}$ must divide the order of the group, which is $\phi(n)$. This gives $\overline{a}^{\phi(n)}=\overline{1}$, or in mod notation $a^{\phi(n)}=1\text{ mod }n$.

Comment: Are you referring to the multiplicative group by $(\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z})^*$ ?

Comment: Yes, exactly :)

Comment: Note that the argument 'the order of $\overline{a}$ must divide the order of the group' is simply Lagrange applied on the subgroup $\langle\overline{a}\rangle$.